# Toggle block in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, events

I'd like to click a header link and have the block directly underneath hide or show (with slideToggle)

Thanks

```
<div class='header'><a href='#'>Header</a></div>

<div class='block'>
<div class='test>Some Text</div>
<div class='test>Some Text</div>
<div class='test>Some Text</div>
</div>

<div class='header'><a href='#'>Header</a></div>

<div class='block'>
<div class='test>Some Text</div>
<div class='test>Some Text</div>
<div class='test>Some Text</div>
</div>

<div class='header'><a href='#'>Header</a></div>

<div class='block'>
<div class='test>Some Text</div>
<div class='test>Some Text</div>
<div class='test>Some Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$("DIV.header A").click(function(){$(this).parent().next().slideToggle();});
```

Comment: whats with the CAPS? Gzip (or deflate) compression works best on similarly cased text (mostly lower or mostly upper).

Comment: No particular reason for the caps other than to denote a difference between a tag reference and a class reference. I didn't know that about gzip, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.header a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function()
{
    $(".header").click(function()
    {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

Or if you want a sliding toggle try:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".header").click(function()
    {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.header').click(function(){
  $(this).next(".block").slideToggle("slow", function(){
         $(".block").not(this).slideUp("slow");
   });
});
```

This code can help to solve your problem.